# Дать разрешение на чтение уведомлений

Tags: android, android-notification

Можно ли программно, без участия пользователя дать приложению (лаунчеру) права на чтение уведомлений? Через `NotificationListenerService`.

<kbd>Безопасность</kbd> → <kbd>Доступ к уведомлениям</kbd>

P.S. Лаунчер будет установлен в системный раздел.